# Div's inside bootstrap columns are overlapping after scaling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

whenever div element wrapped by bootstrap column is scaled larger, it is being overlapped by its right-side neighbour. I do not understand why it is happening.

```
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 red"></div>
        <div class="col-3 green"></div>
        <div class="col-3 yellow"></div>
        <div class="col-3 blue"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Styling:

```
    .red, .green, .yellow, .blue {
        height: 100px;
    }

    .red{
        background-color: red;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    .green{
        background-color: green;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    .yellow{
        background-color: yellow;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    .blue{
        background-color: blue;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    .red:hover, .green:hover, .yellow:hover, .blue:hover{
        transform: scale(1.5);
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/leo9130/snega0ho/

but when same code implemented without bootstrap grid system, div's do not overlap. How do i stop divs overlapping when implemented with grid system and why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because bootstrap adds relative positioning to it's columns. And for relatively positioned divs the default `z-index`. So you have to add `z-index` on hover state.

To achieve your result you can either add `z-index` on hover state of column or you can change the columns `position` to `static` if you do not want `relative` positioning.

```css
.row .col-3:hover {
  z-index: 1; // or you can change the columns position to static if you do not want relative positioning.
}

.red,
.green,
.yellow,
.blue {
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1s;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  transition: 1s;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: 1s;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: 1s;
}

.without>.red,
.green,
.yellow,
.blue {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.red:hover,
.green:hover,
.yellow:hover,
.blue:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<p> Using bootstrap row </p>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 red"></div>
    <div class="col-3 green"></div>
    <div class="col-3 yellow"></div>
    <div class="col-3 blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="without">
  <p>Without bootstrap row</p>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```